# Is stof, strtof deterministic?

Tags: c++, floating-point, deterministic

I'm reading floats from a string. They can be written in a various form, so

```
float f1 = strtof("999999999999.16");
float f2 = stof("000999999999999.1600000");
assert(f1 == f2);
```

Can I be sure that the assertion will be always true, no matter of leading and trailing zeros? The separator will be always a dot, `stof` doesn't handle the comma.

Comment: Not 100% sure.  `stof` calls `strtod` internally so I do not know if that will make a difference or not.  In C++17 it will call `strtof` internally so it should be guaranteed then.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure either. I think this question needs a standards reference. @SnoopDog answer as it stands ought to be regarded as little more than conjecture.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The C11 standard, in 7.22.1.3p9](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.22.1.3p9), has this to say about C's `strtof`/`strtod`/`strtold` (which should be what the C++ versions use underneath, at least judging from [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stof)):

> If the subject sequence has the decimal form and at most `DECIMAL_DIG` (defined in `<float.h>`) significant digits, the result should be correctly rounded.

Given that both of your code lines have the same number of significant digits, they *should* behave the same.  But this is merely conjecture based on the fact that the standard mentions “significant digits” here at all; it is not mentioned anywhere else, and the standard does not say anything more explicit regarding leading (before the decimal point) or trailing (after the decimal point) zeroes.

Comment: are you sure both use `strtof` ? cplusplus mentions `stof` using `strtod` but nothing the like for `stof`

Comment: @tobi303 [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stof) mentions `strtof` as the “_underlying function_” (in a footnote; don’t have a better reference though).

Comment: @mindriot `stof` calls `strtod` until C++17 where it will call `strtof`.

Answer (score 1):

The C++ 14 (§21.5) standard states that:

> `float stof(const string& str, size_t* idx = 0);`
>
> `double stod(const string& str, size_t* idx = 0);`
>
> `long double stold(const string& str, size_t* idx = 0);`
>
> Effects: the first two functions call `strtod(str.c_str(), ptr)` and the third function calls `strtold( str.c_str(), ptr)`. Each function returns the converted result, if any. The argument `ptr` designates a pointer to an object internal to the function that is used to determine what to store at `*idx`. If the function does not throw an exception and `idx != 0`, the function stores in `*idx` the index of the first unconverted element of `str`.

In many cases therefore they will be the same, but the intermediate `double` does open the potential for [double rounding](http://www.exploringbinary.com/double-rounding-errors-in-floating-point-conversions/). E.g. if `str = "1.0000000596046448"`, then the closest `float` (assuming IEEE754 arithmetic) is `1.0000001f`, whereas the closest `double` is exactly halfway between `1.0f` and `1.0000001f`, and so subsequent conversion to `float` will round down to `1.0f`.

That's the theory at least. In practice, however, I am unable to recreate this: http://ideone.com/NMRy14